# ActiveTcl doesn't show thew the output when used with emacs and oz (Mozart 2)

Tags: emacs, oz, mozart, activetcl

I have applied for an online [course](https://courses.edx.org/courses/LouvainX/Louv1.01x/1T2014/info) which requires using Mozart with emacs and ActiveTcl. I have installed all of them based on the provided tutorial but when I feed a simple line of code like:

```
{Browse 5+3}
```

All I've got is:

```
{Browse 5+3}
% -------------------- accepted
```

I am running this on a Windows 8 64bit and tried both ActiveTcl 8.6 and 8.4

Comment: I doing that course too (and I am on windows) the browser is working for me. Have followed instructions in the section `WINDOWS 7 AND WINDOWS 8`?

Comment: @IqbalAnsari I did and no luck then I spent lots of time and made it work on Ubuntu then I got back to Windows and it worked. I am now looking for the reason of this odd behavior out of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Windows 7. The reason was that I tried to install the latest version of Oz prgramming interface (v2.2 alpha - pointed by the link on course side). Installing the latest stable version (1.4), solved the problem for me.

Comment: You mean the problem is not the tcl? interesting, going to check it out